# Executar script apenas uma vez

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Montei um script de alerta em tempo real porém queria que o alerta aparecesse apenas uma vez, ele fica em loop infinito mesmo clicando em fechar. Como faço para ele parar depois do código ser executado ou como executar só uma vez?

Esse é meu script que verifica se  tem novos avisos (o grande problema):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache:true
        });
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#congelando').load('sy_avisos.php');
        }, 1500);
        $( "#congelando").click(function() {
            $('#congelando').load('sy_avisos.php');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Esse é meu script para enviar o alerta com `$_POST`:

```
if ($admin > 4)
   {  
$alertar = fopen("/sy_avisos.php", "w") or die("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar o 
alerta");
$txt = "scriptalert("'.$mensagem.'");script \n";
fwrite($alertar, $txt);
fclose($alertar);
```

Estou também aceitando sugestões pra deixar isso menos complicado, mas estou sem idéias

Comment: Grande problema é o `setInterval`.

Comment: Há algum modo de eu fazer isso com session ou algo do tipo? Estou impacado nisso, sem idéias, sem o intervalo não daria pra verificar se tem novos avisos

Comment: Criar uma função pra chama se tiver nova alerta.

Comment: Pq desmarcou a minha resposta? Teve algum problema?

Comment: Perdão apertei errado achei que não tinha validado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atribua o `setInterval` à uma variável e cancele-o no callback do `.load()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $.ajaxSetup({
      cache:true
   });

   var timer = setInterval(function() {
      $('#congelando').load('sy_avisos.php', function(){ // callback
         clearInterval(timer); // cancela o setInterval
      });
   }, 1500);

   $( "#congelando").click(function() {
      $('#congelando').load('sy_avisos.php');
   });
});
```